# Today all my Java projects are failed to load, the compiler sent me an error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image]

Today I opened VSCode, all my Java projects are failed to load, the compiler sent me an error "Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json."

In another Windows device, it never occured.

In the past, It have not occurred on my computer, but today, it happened, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you try looking at the `launch.json` file that it mentions?

Comment: Did you upgrade your Java installation, so it is now located at a different path? The path to Java usually has a version number in it, so if you upgraded, the old path is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

The warning indicates that there are some issues related with the classpath of the project.

I guess you are working on a project without build tools(Maven/Gradle), but just some folders containing source files. If that's true, you need to update the following workspace setting to make sure all the folders containing source files are set as the source path:

[image]

> BTW, this setting only supported in Lava Language Support@0.77.0+